# Drop `points` along a UIBezierPath such that `center` of points lies ON the path

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

**The problem statement:**

Create a semi-circular dial that has dots along it's circumference. User can pan and `rotate` this dial.

[image]

**Approach:**

- Created a `UIView`
- Added a circle with radius that's double the height of the UIView (using `[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect]` and `CAShapeLayer`)
- Add `dots` (circular `CALayer` objects) along the circumference of this circle, such that the center of these dots lies ON the circumference.

**The obstacle:**

The dots are plotted along a path, but the center of these dots does not lie on the circumference.

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CAShapeLayer* dialLineLayer;

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

        self.dialLineLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        CGRect path = CGRectMake(SCREEN_WIDTH /2 - self.radius, -self.radius, 2 * self.radius, 2 * self.radius);

        [self.dialLineLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:path] CGPath]];
        [self.dialLineLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor la_white10Color] CGColor]];
        [self.dialLineLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
        [self.dialLineLayer setLineWidth:3.0f];
        [self.layer addSublayer:self.dialLineLayer];

        [self addDotsOnLineLayer];
    }

    return self;
}

- (CGFloat) radius {

    // View has an aspect ratio constraint of 75:34 (W:H)

    return SCREEN_WIDTH * 34 / 75 - 10; // Circle radius is 10px less that View's height
}

- (CGFloat) circumference {

    return M_2_PI * self.radius; // 2Pi * radius
}

- (void) addDotsOnLineLayer {

    CGPoint dotPoint = CGPointMake(SCREEN_WIDTH /2 - self.radius - self.radius/2, 0);

    for (double t = 0; t < 2*M_PI; t += 0.2) {

        CGFloat dotRadius = arc4random_uniform(10) - arc4random_uniform(3); // Random radius between 3px and 10px

        CALayer* dotLayer = [CALayer layer];
        dotLayer.frame = CGRectMake(dotPoint.x, dotPoint.y, dotRadius, dotRadius);
        dotLayer.cornerRadius = dotRadius / 2;
        dotLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
        dotLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;

        dotPoint.x = self.radius * cos(t) + (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2);
        dotPoint.y = self.radius * sin(t) + 0;

        [self.dialLineLayer addSublayer:dotLayer];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: (Brace for major 'doh' + facepalm ;) )

```
dotLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, dotRadius, dotRadius);
dotLayer.position = dotPoint;
```

**Explanation**

You are currently positioning the **origin** of your layer on the path. (Remove the corner radius and you'll see what I mean.) However, since you want the **center** of the layer on the path, you have to assign to `.position`.

Note that this is only true, as long as you leave the `.anchorPoint` property of the layer at `{0.5, 0.5}`.
See [Core Animation Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW16) for more info.

Comment: Uh...my entire view is green now.

Comment: Uh...certainly not from the changes I proposed. Make sure you didn't change anything else. - See the edit to my answer

Comment: **'doh' + facepalm**. It works, the radius in some cases went upto 5 digits. Fixed that. Thanks :)